# extract details from mysql table data

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which consists of 1000 records. In the content field there is an anchor tag and I want to extract the author name from this content field and insert it in author field of the same table.

content is

```
 <p>
    When air conditioning, escalators, and advertising appeared, shopping expanded its scale, but also limited its spontaneity. And it became much more predictable, almost scientific. What had once been the most surprising became the most manipulated.</p> 
    <p class="bq_fq_a"> 
    <a id="qut" title="rem_koolhaas"> Rem Koolhaas </a> 
    </p> <br>
```

Here you can see that author is Rem Koolhaas. I want to extract the author and update author field in same table with this. In all cell there are different content but the format is same.All rows consists of anchor.
in addition to that I have three more columns in that table tag1,tag2,tag3. I have 50 tags (like success,fun,morning,beach etc )which I want to match with this content and place them in tag1,tag2,tag3 if it matches

table is

```
  id    content            author     tag1   tag2     tag3

  1     as given above     blank      blank   blank   blank
```

any way to do this?

Comment: Any programming language you know or nothing ? Have you already tried anything or nothing ?

Comment: @Prix i know with php i can do but for that i have to run that script 1000 times for 1000 data but if the content is in billion it will take years but if we can do with sql it will be very fast so i asked brother :)

Comment: @prix i have the code and its working as wellbut i wanted to learn if any better way is there as this is a forum where expert r there

Comment: Doesn't work when you don't listen, gl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL doesn't have the facility of interacting with HTML..can you specify your language..

It can easily done by simply writing these two lines.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $('#qut').html();
   alert(a);
})
</script>
```

Comment: can u please explain how exactly.its php

Comment: It is `JavaScript` code..check my updated answer.I have provided everything for you upcoming question

Answer (score 1):

SQL as a language isn't quite expressive enough to achieve this easily. I'd look to using another language (for example, what you've got the rest of your application written in), reading the data from the MySQL database row-by-row, extracting or transforming the data using an HTML parser, and then inserting the data into a new table in the desired format.